# sp_execute_external_script azure sql database

Tags: sql-server, dataframe

I fetched data from API; I back a csv file . All is made in sp_execute_external_script embedded in Stored procedure.
How can I have Dataframe with headers ?

Because with below code I get column with headers like **(No column name)**

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_GetPreqinData]    Script Date: 07/11/2022 11:05:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetPreData] AS
/*
Test:
    EXEC USP_GetPreData
*/
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @token nvarchar(4000) = ''
    DECLARE @df nvarchar(4000) = ''
    DECLARE   @Table TABLE(line nvarchar(MAX))
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language=N'Python',@script=N'
import requests
import numpy as np
import requests # pip install requests
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
import sqlalchemy as sa # pip install pandas
import csv, io, sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import time
client_id       = "XXXXXXXXXX"
client_secret   = "f2aazc28ae"
username    = "xxx.com"
password    = "ddddd"
tokenUrl        = "https://id.com/connect/token"
tokenHeader     = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
tokenData       = "client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&grant_type=password&scope=pre.feeds.default&username=" + username + "&password=" + password
r = requests.post(url=tokenUrl,headers=tokenHeader,data=tokenData)
token = r.json()["access_token"]

payload = """{...
        }"""
requestHeaders = {"Accept": "text/csv","Authorization": "Bearer " + token} 
#preqinUrl = "https://feeds.pre.com/api/"
r = requests.request("get", "https://feed.com/api/", headers=requestHeaders, data = payload, verify=False)
r.encoding = "utf-8-sig"
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text),sep="|",low_memory=False) # convert requests respons in file, then open the file thru pandas dataframe
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" - ", "_").str.replace(" / ","_").str.replace("/ ","_").str.replace(" : ","_") # replace " - " by _ in headers
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[ /]", "_") # replace space and / by _ in headers
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[()&:?]", "") # replace () by nothing in headers
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("%", "Pct") # replace % by Pct
df.columns = df.columns.str.title() # replace COLUMN_NAME by Column_Name
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("-", "") # replace "-" by "" in headers


stringcols = df.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

all_columns = list(df) # Creates list of all column headers
df[stringcols] = df[stringcols].replace({np.nan: ""})
df[stringcols] = df[stringcols].astype(str)


OutputDataSet = df
'
,@params= N'@df nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @df = @df output


    END
```

My result is:
[Result from my API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6qRl.png)

I want to get data with headers and put in a temporary table.

Comment: If you are just going to `INSERT` the data into a temporary table, why does it also need the columns to have names? The names of the columns in the data to be inserted are completely ignored; it's the ordinal positions that's important. `INSERT INTO #temp (Col1, Col2) SELECT A AS Col2, B AS Col1 FROM dbo.SomeTable;` would insert `A` into `Col1`, and `B` into `Col2`, even though the columns have the opposite aliases. Like wise `INSERT INTO #temp (Col1, Col2) SELECT 'A','B';` would work fine, despite the 2 columns in the `SELECT` have no defined alias.

Comment: Hello I have 149 columns.

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything.

Comment: SO I would have col1 ..... col149 ?
 I'm a begenner so sorry for my stupid question .

Comment: Your temporary table would have 149 columns, yes. I'd recommend "better" names than `col1` and `col149` though.

Comment: So how get the good name of each columns ? instead to put column

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #YourTempTable (AnAppropraiteName varchar(10), AnotherAppropriateName int, ... {147 columns later}, TheLastAppropriateName binary(12));` You *have* to name your columns in a (temporary) table, so define the appropriate names there.